# How to redirect to action of another controller of an referenced project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, response.redirect, redirecttoaction, redirecttoroute

Hi i have a created an another project inside my application.
Now i want to move to the action of the Controller in the new project from the action in my old project.

I tried many things like:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActivityPosting", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "ActivityPosting", action = "ActivityPosting" }));
```

Then...

```
return RedirectToAction("ActivityPosting", "ActivityPosting")
```

But with this it moves to the action but does not show up the View.

 I think the problem may be with the port number.

the older project has port number:http://localhost:18520

and the new project has port number:http://localhost:52146
But i dont know how to redirect to a new Port.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RedirectToAction` method is intended to be used to perform redirects only within the same project. If you want to redirect to another application you should use an absolute url and the `Redirect` method:

```
return Redirect("http://example.com/foo/bar");
```

Comment: Hey thanx it worked..i used the same function and did it like this return Redirect(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ePortfolioURL"] + "/ActivityPosting/"); But can u suggest me a way through which the control goes to action and then view. since with this it directly goes to the view.